# Not possible to ping or reach a container under its local IP

Tags: docker

I have setup a simple flask application in a docker container. My docker file is as follows:

```
FROM python
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "myFlask.py"]
```

I start the container using

```
docker run -d myContainer
```

I retrieve the internal IP address by

```
docker exec -ti <containerID> cat /etc/hosts
```

and it's 172.17.0.2. When I try to ping this address or try to access the REST API using curl I cannot reach it. When I use port forwarding using `-p 5000:5000` as part of the run command I can reach the REST API under localhost:5000. I am working under OS X.

Why can't I reach the container under its local IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds. It's not working under OS X: "Docker Desktop for Mac can’t route traffic to containers."